# Convexity of complex quadratic form $x^*Ax$

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification, convex-analysis, quadratic-forms

It's well-known that $x \mapsto x^\top A x$ is a convex function of $x \in \mathbb R^n$ when the matrix $A$ is (real) positive semidefinite (PSD).  Is this still true when $x \in \mathbb C^n$ and $A$ is Hermitian PSD?  More precisely, is $x \mapsto x^*Ax$ a convex function of $x$ when we view $x$ as a variable in $\mathbb R^{2n}$, i.e., $$\left[\begin{array}{c} \mathrm{Re}(x)\\ \mathrm{Im}(x)\end{array}\right]?$$

**EDITS 2023/2/16:**

Thanks to user550103's comments below, the answer seems to be yes, and a simple proof may be:

Let $f(x)\triangleq x^*Ax=g(h(x))$, where $g(x)=\Vert x\Vert^2$ and $h(x)=\sqrt{A}x$.  Since $g$ is clearly convex, and $h$ is a linear transformation, it follows that $f=g\circ h$ is convex, whether we view $x$ as a variable in $\mathbb C^n$ or $\mathbb R^{2n}$, c.f. $g(h(ax+by))=g(ah(x)+bh(y))\le ag(h(x))+bg(h(y))$.

Please correct me if I'm mistaken somewhere above.

Comment: How do you define convexity in the complex case?

Comment: Yeah, I should clarify the question.  I.e. if we view $x$ in $\mathbb R^{2n}$.

Comment: Well, if you consider $x$ to be in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and thus $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2n \times 2n}$, you are back in the real case, no?

Comment: No, $A=B+jC$.  And the objective function is still $x^*Ax$.

Comment: But the dimensions do not match

Comment: You forgot to mention that $A$ is symmetric in the real case and should be Hermitian in the complex case.

Comment: Or you can view this as a weighted norm in case of complex-valued $x$ as well, i.e., $\| x \|_{A^{1/2}}^2 := x^H A^{H/2} A x = x^H A x $ and $A$ should be Hermitian (and square root of the matrix A exists) as suggested by Rodrigo. We know that such norm is convex.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Isn't $x^\top Ax$ still convex when $x$ is real and $A$ is complex p.s.d.?  So I simply say $A$ is (complex) psd for both cases.

Comment: @syeh_106 Take a look at the definition of convexity.  There is a $\geq$ or $\leq$ in there, right?  is $1 + i2 \leq 1 + i3$?  How do you order complex numbers?  What exactly is complex about the quadratic form?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Understood.  The question is only about $x$ being real or complex.  $A$ is always complex Hermitian psd.

Comment: @syeh_106 What are you doing to ensure that the quadratic form, the output of the function, is real-valued?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo not quite sure what you're getting at...  When $A$ is (complex) Hermitian psd, $x^* A x$ is always real (whether $x$ is real or complex), isn't it?  I can prove its convexity when $x$ is real.  What I'm not sure about is the case when $x$ is complex.  Hence this question.

Comment: @syeh_106 That is my point.  You should be 100% sure that the output is real before worrying about convexity.  Hopefully, someone has already done the work you need — you may want to look for related questions.

Comment: @user550103 Thanks a lot for your comments.  To be clearer, I outlined a simple proof in the question based on your comments.